# Java built program stopped showing select printer dialog

Tags: java, printing

I have a Java program that is built, and is running as a standalone .Jar file. The last build was in start November, and it, along with the previous builds, have been running smoothly.

The function that has stopped working, is where the user wishes to print a receipt, and the program used to show a "Select printer" dialog screen.

But as of today, when the button that runs this function is clicked, nothing happens. The button click effects runs as they should, so the click is registered, but nothing else happens. 
I have tried running the .jar file on both my own, and the users computer with same negative result.

However, when i run the project in IntelliJ, and click the button, everything works as it should, with no exceptions or warinings anywhere. I then tried rebuilding it using this very same code. But again, as a separate .jar file, nothing happens. The user, used the very same function as intended just 2 days ago, with the same .jar file that is not working now.

Edit: Opening the jar file in the commandwindow gives a NullPointerException at the line mentioned below.

A remote debug gives this explanation of the object beleived to cause the exception:

```
JavaFX PrinterJob Printer Microsoft Print to PDF
 Collation = UNCOLLATED
 Copies = 1
 Sides = ONE_SIDED
 JobName = JavaFX Print Job
 Page ranges = null
 Print color = COLOR
 Print quality = NORMAL
 Print resolution = Feed res=600dpi. Cross Feed res=600dpi.
 Paper source = Paper source : Automatic
 Page layout = Paper=Paper: A4 size=210.0x297.0 MM Orient=PORTRAIT leftMargin=54.0 rightMargin=54.0 topMargin=54.0 bottomMargin=54.0
Job Status = NOT_STARTED



public class PrintPage {

public void printSetup(Node node, PageOrientation or)
//The class where it prompts for the printer to be used.

{
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    if (job != null) {
        //Line below gives NullPointerException at the job.showPrintDialog(stage) item
        if (job.showPrintDialog(stage)) print(job, node, or);
    }
    stage.close();
}
```

The errorstack leads from the line above to this part in the javafx PrinterJob class.

```
public synchronized boolean showPrintDialog(Window owner) {
    // TBD handle owner
    if (!isJobNew()) {
        return false;
    } else {
       //This line is the next in the stack
        return jobImpl.showPrintDialog(owner);
    }
}
```

which leads to an error in:

```
com.sun.prism.j2d.print.J2DPrinterJob.showPrintDialog(J2DPrinterJob.java:161)
```

The only null item i see is the Page Ranges, which i can't seem to set.

Comment: Please read the rules and post example code so we can better understand your question and the context.

Comment: Compile the sources with keeping line-number informations and start a remote debug session when running the jar. That should allow you to see what's happening. My money is on some exception that is silently ignored.

Comment: I did a remote debug, it leads to a nullpointerexception. Problem is redescribed in the post. Thank you :-)